# Fiber product of schemes vs. varieties (reality check)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

When I studied smooth manifolds some years ago I've learned that smooth maps $f:X\to B$, $g:Y\to B$ give rise to the so-called fiber product, namely $X\times_BY:=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y\mid f(x)=g(y)\}$.

Recently while studying algebraic geometry, I was surprised to find out that schemes also have fiber products, but this time we define them by an universal property, not by the ordered-pair definition above.

Now I'm trying to understand what happens with varieties (in the sense of Hartshorne's chapter I). Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can see the ordered-pair definition really gives a new well-defined variety $X\times_B Y$ with natural projections
\begin{align*}
\pi_1:X\times_BY &\to X\\
(x,y)&\mapsto x\\\\
\pi_2:X\times_BY &\to Y\\
(x,y)&\mapsto y
\end{align*}

Moreover, if we have morphisms $h_1:Z\to X$ and $h_2:Z\to Y$ with $f\circ h_1=g\circ h_2$, there is a unique morphism:
\begin{align*}
h:Z &\to X\times_BY\\
z&\mapsto  (h_1(z),h_2(z))
\end{align*}

Such that $\pi_1\circ h=\pi_1$ and $\pi_2\circ h=\pi_2$, so the universal property is verified.

I've read the [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6861/fiber-product-of-varieties-vs-schemes-reference) discussion involving universal property and inclusions of subcategories with a right adjoint. This made me more confident that the above makes sense in the big picture, but I'd like to hear someone other than myself saying I'm not crazy.

Comment: Yes, you are not crazy. As your linked answer shows, the fiber product of schemes exists, and if you take the reduced scheme associated to it, you recover the fiber product of varieties.

Still, it's important to understand that, even if you start with varieties, the fiber product taken in the category of schemes might not be reduced, and this is a feature rather than a bug.

Comment: Some comments: it might be helpful for you to say what you mean by varieties (for example, Hartshorne chapter I, geometrically integral scheme of finite type over a field, or something else?). It might also be useful to see that the ordered pair definition from topology is the same as the universal property definition in topology: you can verify the universal property for that construction without too much trouble.

Comment: @KReiser, I only knew the definition as in Hartshorne chapter I, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the post for clarification

Comment: @hunter if $X,Y,B$ are nice schemes (say integral, regular, noetherian) is it still possible that $X\times_BY$ is nonreduced? Or do we still need hypotheses on $f:X\to B$, $g:Y\to B$ in order to guarantee that $X\times_B Y$ is reduced? Which hypotheses?

Comment: @hunter since I've made this post I've just stopped thinking about it (mainly because no one among researchers I read/work with seems to worry about it). I'm basically assuming that when the schemes are nice enough, the fiber product construction is intuitive (i.e. we can work with the ordered-pair construction). But it's still not clear to me what constitutes "nice enough".

Comment: You need more conditions than that (I'm not sure there's a good answer to the question "what conditions" for arbitrary $X,Y,B$). Consider $V(y)$ and $V(y-x^2)$ in $\Bbb A^2$. These are as nice as can be and yet their fiber product over $\Bbb A^2$ is nonreduced: it's $V(x,y^2)$, and since we're working with schemes, that $y^2$ really does matter. As hunter says, this is a feature rather than a bug - it tells you that these subschemes intersect to order two at the origin, and this sort of occurrence is an important foundational piece of some further algebraic geometry like intersection theory.